# Name of foggy effect on statusbar/toolbar used by apps

Tags: java, android

I want to know the name of the effect that Google Play music app uses to put shadow or dark fog like effect to the top of the activity to make the white icons visible on white backgrounds like in the picture:

*Removed link with copyright*

I have tried searching for it without luck. Each time I search for shadow, I find results for the drop down shadow but not the effect. If you could just give me the name of the effect so that I can search for it myself, I would appreciate it a lot.

Comment: It's just a gradient :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a top-down gradient of black (semi-translucent) to black (completely translucent)

If you imagine it being a layer over the album art in an HTML document - a div say - it might have the following css rule applied to it:

```
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0.25) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 20%);
```

This then gives a hint / readability to the white UI icons across the top of the device.

Comment: Thank you so much, Matthew. I had no idea this was a gradient at all. Now I am searching and finally finding more information on what I want to accomplish. I really appreciate it.